# Java in-place algorithm with O(n) time, and extra memory O(1)

Tags: java, big-o

I found this problem on a website (talentbuddy.co) and it's mixing up everything i know about Big-O notation.

Here is the problem statement:

Given an array of integer numbers your task is to print to the standard output (stdout) the initial array, but sorted in a special way:

All negative numbers come first and their relative positions according to the initial array do not change
    the same with the positive integers, but they come last.

Expected complexity: O(N) time, extra memory O(1)

Example input:
-5 2 1 -2 3

Example output:
-5 -2 2 1 3

I understand that O(n) time means the algorithm run-time is proportional to the size of the input, in this case the size of the array, but what does it mean to have extra memory O(1)?

Is it possible to solve this problem using a single for loop? This is what my solution looks like, I'm not sure if its run-time is O(n).

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
class MyClass {
    public static void relative_sort(Integer[] v) {
        int[] positives = new int[v.length];
        int counter = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++){
            if(v[i] < 0){
                System.out.print(v[i] + " ");   
            }else{
                 positives[counter] = v[i];  
                 counter++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i < counter; i++){
            System.out.print(positives[i] + " ");            
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Your extra memory is not `O(1)` because `positives` is size `n`.  If you had an extra array of a static size (say 10) that would still be `O(1)`.

Comment: and i think you run time is `X`, where `O(n) <= X <= 2*O(n)`, you need to get rid of your second loop...and everything will be ok...

Comment: @EugenHalca `2n` is still `O(n)`.

Comment: This problem has appeared on SO before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897280/given-an-array-of-positive-and-negative-integers-re-arrange-it-so-that-you-have ... The accepted answer there uses O(n^2) time when sticking to an array though.

Comment: pretty sure the memory constraint will force you to perform multiple loops in order to use a fixed size temporary space in which you operate on sections of the input instead of attempting to work on the entire data set.

Comment: @DPenner The questions are very similar except this one is considerably easier due to the fact that it just needs to print out the numbers and not actually re-arrange the array.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Ah, very true...I got thrown off by the word "in-place" in the title. The answers on that question could give us insight for this one though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is `O(n)` time.  In the worst case you loop over the array twice and `2n` is still `O(n)`.  However, your extra memory is also `O(n)` because the `positives` array is size `n`, which does not meet the requirement of `O(1)` extra memory.

Ditch the `positives` array entirely and simply loop over the array twice.  On your first pass, print the negatives, on the 2nd pass print the positives.  This is still `2n` making it `O(n)` time and extra memory is `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! It makes perfect sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

The Extra Memory constraint means that any additional memory you need to use must be a constant factor.  That is, it takes `x` bytes of space where `x` is some value that doesn't depend on the size of your input.

Of course, it mentions extra memory because the size of your data will be proportional to itself, so it is referring to any extra (temporary?) space you use for your operations beyond the array itself.

In your solution, you are using an array `positives` that is proportional to the input data.  This is clearly O(n) extra memory, and thus does not fit your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

While you can use two loops , just get rid of the positive array. Instead just use the similar logic as in your first loop

```
class MyClass {
public static void relative_sort(Integer[] v) {
    for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++){
        if(v[i] < 0)
            System.out.print(v[i] + " ");   
    }
    for(int i=0; i < v.length; i++){
        if(v[i] >= 0)
            System.out.print(v[i] + " ");   
    }

}
}
```

Complexity is `O(N)` and you don't even need extra constant memory `O(1)`

Comment: You forgot to remove `positives`.

Comment: Ahh, I got careless, removed it. Thanks !