# How do I sort a list with positives coming before negatives with values sorted respectively?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that contains a mixture of positive and negative numbers, as the following

```
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to sort the list with the positive numbers coming before the negative numbers, respectively sorted as well.

**Desired output:**

```
[1, 2, 9, 10, -12, -5, -4, -2]
```

I was able to figure out the first part sorting with the positive numbers coming before the and negative numbers, unfortunately this does not respectively sort the positive and negative numbers.

```
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda o: not abs(o) == o)
print(lst)

>>> [1, 10, 2, 9, -2, -12, -4, -5]
```

How may I achieve my desired sorting with a pythonic solution?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897280/given-an-array-of-positive-and-negative-integers-re-arrange-it-so-that-you-have and a highly related read

Comment: Do you care where any zeros end up? ​ ​

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You could just use a regular sort, and then bisect the list at 0:

```
>>> lst
[1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
>>> from bisect import bisect
>>> lst.sort()
>>> i = bisect(lst, 0)  # use `bisect_left` instead if you want zeroes first
>>> lst[i:] + lst[:i]
[1, 2, 9, 10, -12, -5, -4, -2]
```

The last line here takes advantage of a slice invariant `lst == lst[:n] + lst[n:]`

Another option would be to use a tuple as a sort key, and rely on [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) ordering of tuples:

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x<0, x))  # use <= instead if you want zeroes last
[1, 2, 9, 10, -12, -5, -4, -2]
```

Comment: I really like both of these options, especially the bisect

Comment: Best way to do it

Comment: Could someone explain to me how that lambda works? (Or just link me to where I can read about that behavior?)

Comment: See below, bisect is the clear winner in terms of perfomance... kudos (need to look into the module)... The lexicon is much worse than bisect, even worse than double list comprehension. Worst of all was using numpy arrays and I was kind of surprised to be honest... might have to post a question as wasn't expecting that and have no clue why, even after using `np.sort`

Comment: hmmm, after being curious on how come and numpy arrays are slower, it turns out that if your list is "small" then `bisect` is faster, however, if it is large then `numpy` is faster.

Comment: I expect they're both O(n*log n) in the asymptotic case, and I don't think there is any possible way to do better than that.

Comment: @ElliotRoberts The lambda returns a tuple. Tuples are sorted by each element (so sort by the first element, then where first element is the same, sort by second element, etc.). `False` is less than `True`, so positive elements will come first. Then within positive elements, it sorts by the actual value (so normal numerical order).

Comment: What does this do in the event the list contains 0?

Comment: `bisect` will put the 0 at the end (use `bisect_left` if you want it at the start).  `lambda` will put it at the start (use `<=` in the lambda if you want it at the end).

Answer (score 9):

Just comparing the different ways.

Results:

```
> Shuffle cost comparison small
shuffle_lst: 0.001181483967229724
shuffle_ar: 0.014688121969811618
> Shuffle cost comparison medium
shuffle_lst: 0.572294642101042
shuffle_ar: 0.3266364939045161
> Shuffle cost comparison large
shuffle_lst: 26.5786890439922
shuffle_ar: 6.284286553971469

                    +cost               -cost
bisectme:    0.004252934013493359    0.003071450046263635
lexicon:     0.010936842067167163    0.009755358099937439
compreh.:    0.0071560649666935205   0.005974580999463797
arrayme:     0.03787591797299683     0.023187796003185213
nplexicon:   0.022204622975550592    0.007516501005738974
npbisect:    0.023507782025262713    0.008819660055451095

                    +cost               -cost
bisectme:    7.716002315981314   7.143707673880272
lexicon:     22.17862514301669   21.606330500915647
compreh.:    8.690494343056343   8.118199700955302
arrayme:     1.5029839979251847      1.1763475040206686
nplexicon:   2.0811527019832283      1.7545162080787122
npbisect:    1.3076487149810418      0.9810122210765257

                    +cost               -cost
bisectme:    180.77819497592282      154.19950593193062
arrayme:     22.476932613993995      16.192646060022525
nplexicon:   41.74795828794595   35.46367173397448
npbisect:    20.13856932707131   13.85428277309984
```

Code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit
from bisect import bisect
from random import shuffle

def shuffle_lst():
    np.random.shuffle(lst)

def shuffle_ar():
    np.random.shuffle(ar)

def bisectme():
    np.random.shuffle(lst)
    lst.sort()
    i = bisect(lst, 0)
    return lst[i:] + lst[:i]

def lexicon():
    np.random.shuffle(lst)
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (x < 0, x))

def comprehension():
    np.random.shuffle(lst)
    return sorted([i for i in lst if i > 0]) + sorted([i for i in lst if i < 0])

def arrayme():
    np.random.shuffle(ar)
    return np.concatenate([np.sort(ar[ar >= 0]), np.sort(ar[ar < 0])], axis=0)

def nplexicon():
    np.random.shuffle(ar)
    return ar[np.lexsort((ar, ar < 0))]

def numpybisect():
    np.random.shuffle(ar)
    ar.sort()
    i = ar.__abs__().argmin()
    return np.concatenate((ar[i:], ar[:i]))


nloops = 1000

lst = list(range(-10**1, 0, 1)) + list(range(10**1, -1, -1))
ar = np.array(lst)
print("> Shuffle cost comparison small")
cost_shuffle_list_small = timeit(shuffle_lst, number=nloops)
print("shuffle_lst:", cost_shuffle_list_small)
cost_shuffle_array_small = timeit(shuffle_ar, number=nloops)
print("shuffle_ar:", cost_shuffle_array_small)

lst = list(range(-10**4, 0, 1)) + list(range(10**4, -1, -1))
ar = np.array(lst)
print("> Shuffle cost comparison medium")
cost_shuffle_list_medium = timeit(shuffle_lst, number=nloops)
print("shuffle_lst:", cost_shuffle_list_medium)
cost_shuffle_array_medium = timeit(shuffle_ar, number=nloops)
print("shuffle_ar:", cost_shuffle_array_medium)

nloops = 100

lst = list(range(-10**6, 0, 1)) + list(range(10**6, -1, -1))
ar = np.array(lst)
print("> Shuffle cost comparison large")
cost_shuffle_list_large = timeit(shuffle_lst, number=nloops)
print("shuffle_lst:", cost_shuffle_list_large)
cost_shuffle_array_large = timeit(shuffle_ar, number=nloops)
print("shuffle_ar:", cost_shuffle_array_large)

print()

nloops = 1000

## With small lists/arrays
lst = list(range(-10**1, 0, 1)) + list(range(10**1, -1, -1))
ar = np.array(lst)

print("\t\t\t\t\tw/o pen.\t\t\t\tw. pen.")

foo = timeit(bisectme, number=nloops)
print("bisectme:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_small)

foo = timeit(lexicon, number=nloops)
print("lexicon:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_small)

foo = timeit(comprehension, number=nloops)
print("compreh.:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_small)

foo = timeit(arrayme, number=nloops)
print("arrayme:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_array_small)

foo = timeit(nplexicon, number=nloops)
print("nplexicon:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_array_small)

foo = timeit(numpybisect, number=nloops)
print("npbisect:\t", foo, "\t",  foo - cost_shuffle_array_small)

print()

## With medium lists/arrays
lst = list(range(-10**4, 0, 1)) + list(range(10**4, -1, -1))
ar = np.array(lst)

print("\t\t\t\t\tw/o cost\t\t\t\tw. cost")

foo = timeit(bisectme, number=nloops)
print("bisectme:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_medium)

foo = timeit(lexicon, number=nloops)
print("lexicon:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_medium)

foo = timeit(comprehension, number=nloops)
print("compreh.:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_medium)

foo = timeit(arrayme, number=nloops)
print("arrayme:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_array_medium)

foo = timeit(nplexicon, number=nloops)
print("nplexicon:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_array_medium)

foo = timeit(numpybisect, number=nloops)
print("npbisect:\t", foo, "\t",  foo - cost_shuffle_array_medium)

print()


## With large lists/arrays
nloops = 100

lst = list(range(-10**6, 0, 1)) + list(range(10**6, -1, -1))
ar = np.array(lst)

print("\t\t\t\t\tw/o cost\t\t\t\tw. cost")

foo = timeit(bisectme, number=nloops)
print("bisectme:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_list_large)

foo = timeit(arrayme, number=nloops)
print("arrayme:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_array_large)

foo = timeit(nplexicon, number=nloops)
print("nplexicon:\t", foo, "\t", foo - cost_shuffle_array_large)

foo = timeit(numpybisect, number=nloops)
print("npbisect:\t", foo, "\t",  foo - cost_shuffle_array_large)

print()
```

Comment: 1np.sort(ar)` takes 3/4 of the time; only 1/4 is spent on the masking and concatenation.

Comment: I'm not sure about the fairness of the fact that 1) the list is presorted and 2) even if it weren't, `bisectme` sorts the list in place, affecting all following tests.

Comment: 2*10^2=200, and 200 is much easier to read and write. But it does makes you look very smart when you write 2*10^2.

Comment: @JohnSmith This still sorts the list on the first loop and then it's sorted for all subsequent loops. This may unfairly advantage the in place sorts. Each loop really needs it's own copy.

Comment: argh yes... misinterpreted, you mean each loop of the timeit... true... moved the shuffle in each of the functions... that will take a while to run... will update when finishes

Comment: @jpmc26 how about now.... Does this fix what you meant? But the results are.... well I leave them to what they are...

Answer (score 6):

Create two lists, one with positive value and another with the negative values and then sort the content of each list the way you like. For example:

```
my_list = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
pos_list, neg_list = [], []
for item in my_list:
    if item < 0: 
        neg_list.append(item)
    else:
        pos_list.append(item)

final_list = sorted(pos_list) + sorted(neg_list)
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just sort by the negative of the element's inverse:

```
from __future__ import division

sorted(lst, key=lambda i: 0 if i == 0 else -1 / i)
```

Taking the inverse switches the order of the magnitudes (larger numbers in the middle, smaller on the outside). Taking the negative reverses the order (positives first, negatives last).

Be aware of the size of your numbers of course and if they'll cause any over- or underflow issues.

Comment: that's also slow (~60s) for 2*10^4 unsorted lists like above

Comment: @JohnSmith Yes, not super fast, but simple and pretty intuitive.

Comment: Clever idea!  A glance at the [graph of `f(x) = -1/x`](https://www.google.com/search?q=-1%2Fx+graph) helped me to understand how this works.

Answer (score 4):

Create two separate list. One positive values one with negative values. sort the negative list, then concatenate them together:

```
>>> lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
>>> sorted([i for i in lst if i > 0]) + sorted([i for i in lst if i =< 0])
[1, 2, 9, 10, -12, -5, -4, -2]
>>>
```

Comment: One of your comparisons should check against 0 too, >= 0 or <= 0 to include zeros also.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
ar = np.array(lst)
lst = list(np.concatenate([np.sort(ar[ar >= 0]), np.sort(ar[ar < 0], reverse = True)], axis = 0))
print(lst)
```

And if you don't have to use a list but are happy with numpy arrays then you don't have to pay the costs of casting, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
ar = np.array([1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2])
ar = np.concatenate([np.sort(ar[ar >= 0]), np.sort(ar[ar < 0])], axis = 0)
print(ar)
```

Comment: While `numpy` appears to be a great module, it seems like it is overkill with what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: hmmm, after being curious on how come and numpy arrays are slower, it turns out that if your list is "small" then `bisect` is faster, however, if it is large then `numpy` is faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2])
l[np.lexsort((l, l < 0))]

array([  1,   2,   9,  10, -12,  -5,  -4,  -2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to wmin for the logic of his solution (accepted answer) which is great. So for completeness, a similar answer to this but based on numpy, which is significantly faster for anything else other than small lists/arrays, is as follows:

```
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
ar = np.array(lst)
ar.sort()
i = ar.__abs__().argmin()
np.concatenate((ar[i:], ar[:i]))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the *most* Pythonic, and it certainly does not have any bells-and-whistles, but IMO it's a clear and understandable code:

```
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]

pos = list()
neg = list()

for i in lst:
    neg.append(i) if i < 0 else pos.append(i)

print(sorted(pos) + sorted(neg))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list in place twice like so:

```
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]
lst.sort()
lst.sort(key=int(0).__gt__)      # key is True for items <= 0
```

This takes advantage of the fact the python `sort` function/method is *stable*.  That means that items with the same value or key stay in the same order.  The first sort puts all the items in order from smallest to largest.  For the second sort, all the items < 0 get a key of True, all the items >= 0 get a key of False.  Because True (1) > False (0), the second sort moves all the negative items to the end, without changing the order of the negative items.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is another solution: *

```
lst = [1, -2, 10, -12, -4, -5, 9, 2]  # list of values.
x = sorted(lst) # x : [-12, -5, -4, -2, 1, 2, 9, 10]
k, m = [], []  # k : [1, 2, 9, 10] # M : [-12, -5, -4, -2]
for i in x:
    if i > 0:
        k.append(i)
    else:
        m.append(i)
w = k + m # w : [1, 2, 9, 10, -12, -5, -4, -2]
print(w)
```